# Apache Felix Event Admin - Logging

Tags: java, osgi, publish-subscribe, apache-felix

I'm trying to implement a publish/subscribe pattern with the Apache Felix Event admin. My piece of code it's working, but I would like to see all the associated logs

The official documentation only states that the default loglevel is WARNING, but I can't understand where it's actually logging. Also, it's not very clear how can I can change the loglevel (I suppose trhough -D java property but I'm not sure)

Thanks

Comment: What are you using? Felix? Karaf? Equinox?

Comment: Apache Felix 5.4.0

Comment: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html. Search for felix.log.level property.